# Perl/CGI : format several images

Tags: perl, image, cgi

Need a bit more help please...
I need to display 24 times :
[image: yellow] or
[image: red] or
[image: green] (depending on speed/duplex on the port)
But those images have to be displayed in the switch's image : [image: switch]

How to do to get all images well formated ??
To know which color to choose, I wrote a perl script using Net::SNMP to get infos about speed, duplex...

Thanks guys.
Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm. Actually, I'd be more tempted to take the images and use CSS styles to color them.

For example, if you took one of those and turned the colored areas transparent, you could place them using CSS, and change the background color, either with generated Perl or with JavaScript on the fly.

It gets a little complex, admittedly; you'll have to create 26 styles (one for each switch), placing them appropriately. You'll need two images (right-side up and upside-down). You'd also have

```
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
```

and so on. But then it's just a matter of adding the appropriate class to the appropriate div; no need to load six different image variants (just two), and you gain the ability to adjust the colors to be anything you want with just a change to the CSS, and do so dynamically if you like.

Does that make any sense?

Comment: (Obviously, I wouldn't suggest naming the class `.yellow`, but I'd use `.t1000`, `.t100`, `.fulldup`, `.halfdup`, and so on.)

Answer (score 1):

[PerlMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php)

Comment: I red about this lib, but it can only return image type ? How to return text+images (good position) +links ?

Comment: ImageMagick can place text and images on top of another image. You just need to read the API for the relevant calls. As far as links, read about HTML's `map` tag.